# How to use a javascript variable in jquery GET 'data: '

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, get

I have been working hard to get my jquery form to work properly. Everything is working as expected and returns a response like I want it too. However, I am stuck using some static test data to send to the jquery thing. I would like for something like this to work:

```
var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

function sendData()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/contact.php',
    data: { first_name: 'fn', last_name: 'ln' },
    success: success
    });
}

function success(success)
{
    var success_message = success;
    document.getElementById("script_message").innerHTML = success_message;
}
```

I just get fn and ln returned though, rather than the values in the input form fields.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

---

Here it is working, thanks for your help!

```
function sendData()
{

    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/contact.php',
    data: { first_name: fn, last_name: ln },
    success: success
    });
}

function success(success)
{
    var success_message = success;
    document.getElementById("script_message").innerHTML = success_message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove quotes from your variables, because quotes make them string:

```
data: { first_name: fn, last_name: ln },
```

And either, make those variables global by removing `var` from it, like

```
fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value; //var removed
ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value; //var removed
```

or
add it inside your function like

```
function sendData() {
   var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
  ..rest of your ajax
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, that did not work though. Now nothing shows up for first and last name.

Comment: Thank you! I moved them inside the function and it works like a charm!